# I want to add a conditional in a Jenkins pipeline that only runs when a submodule has changed

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, conditional-statements, git-submodules

I'm using Jenkins with git. Jenkins checks out the current commit as part of a Pipeline.  Sometimes, checking out the new commit will leave a submodule dirty.  Jenkins also recursively updates the submodules at this point.

This all works fine.

What I want to do is conditionally run a powershell command *only* when the submodule is dirty after the checkout stage.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: Does it have to be a powershell command? Could it be Bash?

Comment: It's a windows machine so no bash.  I assume anything in bash can be translated to powershell though.

Comment: Probably, but not by me. I'm sure someone who knows powershell will reply. If not, I'll post some solution in Bash. Note that [Git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) provides a Bash emulation (in case that ends up being useful to you).

Comment: couldn't you just cd into the submodule and do a git status/diff to see check if it is dirty and use this as an if condition?

Comment: Yes, this is what I do now, manually.  But I want to do this as part of a Jenkins Pipeline.

Ideally I want this to be a conditional stage in the Jenkins Pipeline.  But I'd settle for a powershell script that handles this.